# Identical Java sources compile to binary differing classes

Tags: java, compilation

Can anyone explain how identical Java sources can end up compiling to *binary* differing class files?

The question arises from the following situation:

We have a fairly large application (800+ classes) which has been branched, restructured then reintegrated back into the trunk. Prior to reintegration, we merged the trunk into the branch, which is standard procedure.

The end result was a set of directories with the branch sources and a set of directories with the trunk sources. Using Beyond Compare we were able to determine that both sets of sources were identical. However, on compiling (*same JDK* using maven hosted in IntelliJ v11) we noticed that about a dozen or so of the class files were different.

When we decompiled the source for each pair of apparently different class files we ended up with the same java source, so in terms of the end result, it doesn't seem to matter. But why is it that just a few of the files are different?

Thanks.

---

Additional thought:

If maven/javac compiles files in a different sequence, might that affect the end result?

Comment: different jdk versions? I imagine the optimisations may be different for different versions.

Comment: Using javap -c -v (thanks Peter Lawrey) and viewing the respective outputs using Beyond Compare (great tool, love it!) I can confirm that item 5 on Stephen C's (thanks Stephen C) response gives part of the answer here. In several of the cases, the constant pool order is different. However, I'm fairly sure the classpath is the same for both, but the order of compilation may be different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that the JDK versions, build tool versions, and build / compilation options are identical, I can still think of a number of *possible* sources of differences:

1. Timestamps - class files may<sup>1</sup> contain compilation timestamps.  Unless you run the compilations at exactly the same times, different compilations of the same file would result different timestamps.
2. Source filename paths - each class file includes the pathname of the source file.  If you compile two trees with different pathnames the class files will contain different source pathnames.
3. Values of imported compile-time constants - when a class `A` uses a compile-time constant defined in another class `B` (see JLS for the definition of a "compile time constant"), the value of the constant is incorporated into `A`s class file.  So if you compile `A` against different versions of `B` (with different values for the constants), the code of `A` is likely to be different.
4. Differences due to `identityHashcode` being used in `HashMap` keys by the compiler could lead to differences in map iteration order in some step. This could affect `.class` file generation in a way that is not significant, but still shows up as a `.class` file difference.  For example, constant pool entries could end up in a different order.
5. Differences in signatures of external classes / methods; e.g. if you changed a dependency version in one of your POM files.
6. Differences in the effective build classpaths might result in differences in the order in which imported classes are found.  This might in turn result in non-significant differences in the order of entries in the class file's Constant Pool.  This could happen due to things such as:

   - files appearing in different order in the directories of external JAR files,
   - files being compiled in different order due to the source files being in different order when your build tool iterates them<sup>2</sup>, or
   - parallelism in the build (if you have that enabled).

There is a possible workaround for the problem with file ordering: use the undocumented `-XDsortfiles` option as described in [JDK-7003006](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7003006).  (Kudos to @Holger for knowing about that.)

Note that you don't normally see the actual order of files in file system  directories.  Commandline tools like `ls` and `dir`, and file browsers will typically sort the entries (in name or timestamp order) before displaying them.

---

<sup>1 - This is compiler dependent.  Also, it is not guaranteed that `javap` will show the timestamps ... if they are present.</sup>

<sup>2 - The OS gives no guarantees that listing a directory (at the syscall level) will return the file system objects in a deterministic order ... or the same order, if you have removed and re-added files.</sup>

---

I should add that the first step to identifying the cause of the differences is to work out exactly what they are.  You probably need (needed) to do that the hard way - by manually decoding a pair of class files to identify the places where they actually differences ... and what the differences actually mean.

Comment: Stephen, I can see no evidence in the decompilation for items 1,2 and items 3 and 4 do not apply here (the sources, including the POMs, are identical remember). However, I think items 5 is feasible as the sequence the compiler compiles may be different in either case.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I think item 5 and onwards answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

When you compare using beyond compare, comparision is done based on contents of the files. But in the build process just the timestamp of the source files are checked for change. So it your source file's lastmodified date changes it will be recompiled.

Comment: I should have clarified that all files were compiled for both sets of sources (i.e there were no class files existing prior to compilation)

Answer (score 1):

Different JDK produce different binary classes (optimizations, but also class version number). There are compilation options, too (a JDK may compile in an older format, or it can add debug information).

Comment: I've edited to confirm the same JDK and compilation options, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Different versions of Java can add different meta data which is often ignored by a decompiler.

I suggest you try using `javap -c -v` for more of the details in a file. If this doesn't help you can use the ASMifierClassVisitor which looks at every byte.

Answer (score 1):

same JDK can also have different output depending on how you compile.
you can compile with or without debug info, you can compile to run in an older version, each option will result in other classes.